# What is the edge glow shading technique used in Super Mario called?

Tags: shaders, graphics, terminology, glow

What is this Super Mario shading technique (the edge glow) called? It can best be seen on the legs.

[image: Mario has a clear white glow outlining his model.]

Comment: Turn [Fresnel on here](http://github.prideout.net/giza/demos/BasicLighting.html)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Rim lighting.

http://blog.wolfire.com/2009/09/character-rim-lighting/

Basically you increase the brightness of a surface the more the tangent is pointing away from the camera.

Comment: Beaten... by 15 seconds, ha!

Answer (score 7):

Looks to me to either be the Fresnel Falloff shader effect or some variant of a Rim Lighting. The pixels near the edges appear to be just brightened. You can see a similar effect described [here](http://nimblebit.blogspot.ca/2008/02/rim-lighting-extravabonanzathon.html).